# Newspaper Simulator / Fake News Generator

Tags: windows, gratis, offline, document-converter

I want to convert a formatted text (I can come up with Rich Text, Word Document or HTML) into a graphics so that it looks like it were printed in a newspaper and then got scanned.

That software

- takes a formatted text (limited formatting options: just a header style and text style, no colors) as input, either by reading a file (.DOCX, .RTF or .HTML) or via clipboard
- generates a high-resolution graphics as output (.JPG or .PNG)
- adds a (news)paper-structure as background
- performs a dot raster operation on the image
- ideally adds some typical newspaper columns
- ideally applys newspaper fonts (like Serif fonts for text and non-serif fonts for titles)
- adds some rotation / distortion so that it looks like inserted in the scanner at a slight angle (~0.5 to 1.0 degrees is enough)

I want it to

- work on Windows 10
- be gratis
- work offline (without Internet connection)

Example:

Input

[image: Input document]

Output

[image: Output image]

Comment: This is old news, I read that in the NYT last week lol. With 3000 flags per day to handle I expect the impact on my career to be very negative ;-)